# Can chainId be overflow?

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I was studying the uniswap V2 smart contract, and I saw that in the constructor part, using assembly, the value of the chainId was set in a variable.

```
    constructor() public {
        uint chainId;
        assembly {
            chainId := chainid
        }
        DOMAIN_SEPARATOR = keccak256(
            abi.encode(
                keccak256('EIP712Domain(string name,string version,uint256 chainId,address verifyingContract)'),
                keccak256(bytes(name)),
                keccak256(bytes('1')),
                chainId,
                address(this)
            )
        );
    }
```

Is it possible to create a blockchain whose chainId will encounter overflow when the constructor is executed?

Is there a law to choose chainId for new blockchains?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the Contract, because I am supprised there are no comments of such explaining it.

Comment: https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2ERC20.sol#L27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChainId has a size of 256 bits, meaning there can not be a number that is larger than that in blockchain saved in a single variable. So to answer your question, no there can not be any overflow.

The following article might help:
https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1344